# Why I can not limit an input's value length with Angular NgModel?

Tags: angular, typescript, two-way-binding, angular2-ngmodel

I have an input field with two way binding and I want to change the user input to uppercase and limit it to 3 characters. I'm doing this in the setter of the variable. The uppercase replacement works if I try to do a substring it does not update the field value anymore, the property is correctly updated though.

If I enter "abc" it replaces it correctly to "ABC" but as soon as I type more than 3 characters, the other characters are not removed. For example "abcde" displays "ABCde" in the input.
Please see the stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpuh8a

```
<input type="text" id="airport" name="airport" [(ngModel)]="airport">
```

```
private _airport = '';
get airport(): string {
  return this._airport;
}
set airport(value: string) {
  this._airport = value.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
}
```

I know that I can limit the field length using maxlength and it works but I want to understand why what I'm doing here is not working.

I've tried calling a method in ngModelChange as well but the result is the same

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand the viewModel and model.

When you type the fourth character, model still is `ABC`, so Angular doesn't update the viewModel ([Source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L221)), but the input element will still respond to your typing.

The solution to this problem is to manually control the input element value. or set `maxLength`.

```html
<label for="airport">Airport </label>
<input #input type="text" id="airport" name="airport" [ngModel]="airport" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
{{ airport }}
```

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('input', { static: false }) input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  airport = '';

  onChange(value: string) {
     this.airport = value.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
     this.input.nativeElement.value = this.airport;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwwjs7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, this is working well, even with [(ngModel)] instead of (ngModelChange). Now I need to understand the usage of ViewChild, I suppose I need to read the doc :)